# Web scraping data using Python Beautiful Soup - can't extract field

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the ticker (South Africa 40) field from an IG Index page using Python Beautiful Soup, but I can't retrieve it.

The webpage I am trying to get data from is https://www.ig.com/uk/ig-indices/south-africa-40?siteId=igm

HTML code with the ticker data:

```
<div class="ma-content title">
    <h1>South Africa 40</h1>

        <p>
            .........some text..........
        </p>

</div>
```

I have tried this:

```
name = soup.select('div.ma-content title h1')[0].text
```

but get the error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "IGIndexDataScrape_Minute_v0.1.py", line 30, in 
>       name = soup.select('div.ma-content title h1')[0].text IndexError: list index out of range

Any advice / code correction on the above will be really helpful.

Here is the complete code for straight copy and paste:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import csv
from datetime import datetime

from lxml import html
import requests

quote_page = ['https://www.ig.com/uk/ig-indices/south-africa-40?siteId=igm']

data = []
for pg in quote_page:
page = urllib2.urlopen(pg)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

name = soup.select('div.ma-content title h1')[0].text

sell_price = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'price', 'id':'bid'}).text
data.append(sell_price)

buy_price = soup.find('span', attrs={'class':'price', 'id':'ofr'}).text
data.append(buy_price)

print sell_price + "\t\t" + buy_price + name

#    data.append(name, sell_price, buy_price)
#    print name + "\t\t" + sell_price + "\t\t" + buy_price
```

Comment: Please edit your post and properly format the code: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: The css is wrong. It should be `div.ma-content.title` or just `div.title`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `find_all` instead of `select`? Something like:

```
name_div = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'ma-content title'})[0]
name = name_div.find('h1').text
```

Comment: this will for sure work but I think you forgot a `}` ;)

Comment: Thanks very much guys. The above solution works.  :)

Comment: @manjeetss I did nothing all thanks go to Sam. Glad it works anyway happy scraping :)